# Как подгрузка контента страниц с помощью AJAX повлияет на результаты в поисковиках

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, seo

У меня есть сайт на wordpress с очень большими страницами.

https://www.instale.co.il/

Загрузка такой страницы занимает относительно много времени. Слайдеры и прочий тяжелый функционал задерживают подгрузку остального содержимого.

Все, что можно было добавить для ускорения вроде есть, webp формат, плагин кеширования (wp rocket). Оценки PageSpeedInsights вполне удовлетворительные.

Я придумал дополнительно сделать следующее. Подгружать большую часть контента по Ajax например при первом скроле.

Изначально показывать только первые критичные секшены.
Получается, что в html коде страниц будет далеко не все, что фактически есть на сайте.

Вопрос в том, как это повлияет на результаты в поисковых системах. Стоит ли вообще это делать?

Comment: не стоит, так как боты не смогут отслеживать контент, а вот инитить слайдеры и тому подобный функционал можно после скрола

Comment: Я тоже подумал про это, вот и решил спросить. Получается можно слайдеры, формы и остальной менее важный для поисковиков контент подгружать по ajax.